# Build libbacktrace for android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use a libbacktrace in my android app and I do not know how to build it...

Now I trying to build the lib by the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ndk-build \
    APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=libbacktrace/Android.mk \
    NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. \
    APP_STL=stlport_static \
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=include \
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=../../../android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include \
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=../../../android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/include/ \
    APP_PLATFORM=android-19
```

and I have errors:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: backtrace <= BacktraceImpl.cpp
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp: In member function 'virtual std::string Backtrace::FormatFrameData(const backtrace_frame_data_t*)':
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:117:48: error: expected ')' before 'PRIxPTR'
     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "#%02zu pc %0*" PRIxPTR "  %s (%s+%" PRIuPTR ")",
                                                ^
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:119:58: error: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Werror=format=]
              frame->func_name.c_str(), frame->func_offset);
                                                          ^
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:119:58: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:121:48: error: expected ')' before 'PRIxPTR'
     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "#%02zu pc %0*" PRIxPTR "  %s (%s)", frame->num,
                                                ^
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:122:87: error: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Werror=format=]
              (int)sizeof(uintptr_t)*2, relative_pc, map_name, frame->func_name.c_str());
                                                                                       ^
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:122:87: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:124:48: error: expected ')' before 'PRIxPTR'
     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "#%02zu pc %0*" PRIxPTR "  %s", frame->num,
                                                ^
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:125:61: error: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Werror=format=]
              (int)sizeof(uintptr_t)*2, relative_pc, map_name);
                                                             ^
libbacktrace/BacktraceImpl.cpp:125:61: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/backtrace/BacktraceImpl.o] Error 1
```

I understood that I doing something wrong but I don't know what...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with the definition of `PRIxPTR` (it should be a macro).

IIRC type is the "main" letter in the *printf()* format, e.g. `i` in `%i`, see the spec of printf format for details. (Oops... it is officially called a *specifier*, and there's also an optional *length sub-specifier*, but you see the point. But M$ calls them "printf Type Field Characters").

In C, `"a" "b"` is the same as `"ab"`, so after `#define X "i"` the text `"%" X` is equivalent to `"%i"`.